# Get the number of white spaces at line beginning

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I tried the following implementation:

```
NSString *string = @"    Test";
NSString *spaces = @"";

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
[scanner scanCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] intoString:&spaces];
```

The number of whitespaces should be `[spaces length]`. However, all tests I tried always return `0`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setCharactersToBeSkipped:`. The docs say,

> The default set of characters to skip is the whitespace and newline character set.

So it just silently skips the whitespace prefix.

There is another way to do it:

```
NSUInteger prefixLength = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet: 
    [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```